# How to run Google Translate v3 using KEYAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, translation

So This is what I try:

```
# running Translate API
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build('translate', 'v3', developerKey=APIKEY)

# use the service
inputs = ['is it really this easy?', 'amazing technology', 'wow']
print(service)
outputs = service.translate_text().list(source='en', target='fr', q=inputs).execute()
# print outputs
for input, output in zip(inputs, outputs['translations']):
  print(u"{0} -> {1}".format(input, output['translatedText']))
```

This is what I get:

```
<googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object at 0x7f35c6755278>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cae7afc56ddd> in <module>()
      6 inputs = ['is it really this easy?', 'amazing technology', 'wow']
      7 print(service)
----> 8 outputs = service.translate_text().list(source='en', target='fr', q=inputs).execute()
      9 # print outputs
     10 for input, output in zip(inputs, outputs['translations']):

AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'translate_text'
```

In Translate v3 [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-translate/blob/master/samples/snippets/translate_v3_translate_text.py) I can not find how to use APIKEY instead of `project_id`... Similar API worked for v2 (example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hPH7skySCZR-ZMJ6TmYLN1ug6vbq2cpb#scrollTo=2w4bHiuYXywg)).

So How to run Google Translate v3 using KEYAPI?

Comment: What is wrong with using project_id instead of an api_key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V3 doesn't support API KEY, please see [this page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/editions#supported_features) for more details.